# I have 4 nested div tags and when I print text using find_all, it prints the text 4 times

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am extracting text from an html file which contains a lot of div tags. However, at some places there are say 4 nested div tags and when I print text, it prints it 4 times.

```
<div>
    <div id="PGBRK" style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; WIDTH: 100%; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt">
        <div id="PN" style="PAGE-BREAK-AFTER: always; WIDTH: 100%">
            <div style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 100%"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">27</font></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For example, here if I do:

```
for item in page_soup.find_all('div'):
    if "27" in item.text:
            print(item)
```

It prints the number 27 four times and therefore messes up whole text.
How can I get my code to only print the nested text once?

**EDIT 1:**
This works well for this part of the code. But like I said, this is only true at some places. For example, when I do:

```
for item in page_soup.find_all('div', recursive = False):
    print(item)
```

It does not print anything. For reference, [this](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/4904/000000490412000013/ye11aep10k.htm) is the document I am trying to scrape.

**EDIT 2:**
From the given html, I am trying to extract the section "ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS".

```
should_print = False

for item in page_soup.find_all('div'):
    if "ITEM 1A." in item.text:
        should_print = True
    elif "ITEM 1B." in item.text:
        break
    if should_print:
        print(item)
```

So I am printing everything starting from ITEM 1A. until it finds ITEM 1B.
Here at some places there are nested div tags, which gets printed multiple times with this piece of code.

If I do, recursive = False, it does not print anything.

Comment: your current code tries to print the entire element, not only the text. Eventually, you need text or element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question since I finally got it to work.

The solution was easy, I was just thinking it too hard.
I just added the condition that the parent of the item should not be "div". Now the program does not print the text multiple times.

```
should_print = False

for item in page_soup.find_all('div'):
    if item.name == "div" and item.parent.name != "div"
        if "ITEM 1A." in item.text:
            should_print = True
        elif "ITEM 1B." in item.text:
            break
        if should_print:
            print(item)
```

Thank you everyone for your contributions. Appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the option `text = "27"` to search the divs by text and identify only that exact div. The below code should work fine. If you want to get all the divs then just remove the `text = "27"` or replace it with what text that you want to find. You can also use `recursive = False` to get only the top level divs.

### Edit 1:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

t = '''
<div>
27
</div>
<div>
<div id="PGBRK" style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; WIDTH: 100%; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt">

<div id="PN" style="PAGE-BREAK-AFTER: always; WIDTH: 100%">

<div style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 100%"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">27</font></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
'''

page_soup = BeautifulSoup(t, 'html.parser')

for item in page_soup.find_all('div', text="27"):
    print(item.text)
```

### Edit 2:

I have added a specific code that works for your problem specifically. Try the below code. The div range that you are expecting is from `567 - 715` with page numbers removed.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get(
    r'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/4904/000000490412000013/ye11aep10k.htm')
t = resp.text

page_soup = BeautifulSoup(t, 'html.parser')

s = 'body > div:not(#PGBRK)'

for i in page_soup.select(s)[567:715]:
   print(i.get_text(strip=True))
```

Comment: I edited my question and added a little more detail. It would be nice if you could take a look. Thanks :)

Comment: @RishabGupta I have edited my answer. Hope this helps. Also provide more detail on what is the exact content that you want to scrap from the original document.

Comment: I have added another EDIT with more clarification. Sorry about that. Should've done that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option

```
import bs4, re

html = '''<div>
<div id="PGBRK" style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; WIDTH: 100%; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt">

<div id="PN" style="PAGE-BREAK-AFTER: always; WIDTH: 100%">

<div style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 100%"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">27</font></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
elements = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('27'))
print(elements)
```

output

```
[u'27']
```

Answer (score 0):

> printing everything starting from `ITEM 1A`. until it finds `ITEM 1B`

Trough `.string` attribute (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/4904/000000490412000013/ye11aep10k.htm'
html_doc = requests.get(url).content
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

do_print = False
for el in page_soup.find_all('div'):
    if el.string:
        if "ITEM 1A" in el.string:
            do_print = True
        elif "ITEM 1B" in el.string:
            break
    if do_print:
        print(el)
```

The output (I'll show the representative start and end blocks without middle part, to make a short dump):

```
<div align="justify" style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; TEXT-DECORATION: underline">ITEM 1A.   RISK FACTORS</font></font></div>
<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block"><br/>
</div>
<div align="justify" style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">GENERAL RISKS OF OUR REGULATED OPERATIONS</font></div>
<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block">
<div align="justify" style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt"><font style="FONT-STYLE: italic; DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold"> </font></div>
<div align="justify" style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt"><font style="FONT-STYLE: italic; DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">The regulatory environment in Ohio has recently become unpredictable and increasingly uncertain. – Affecting AEP and OPCo</font></div>
<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block"><br/>
.....
<div style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 100%"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">37</font></div>
<div style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 100%">
<hr noshade="" size="2" style="COLOR: black"/>
</div>
<div id="HDR">
<div align="right" id="GLHDR" style="WIDTH: 100%"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 8pt">  </font></div>
</div>
<div align="right" id="GLHDR" style="WIDTH: 100%"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 8pt">  </font></div>
<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block"> </div>
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it still prints the page numbers and some text multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think that is a cool question, and I don't see a simple answer if you want to generalize it to find out what text there is at each level without resorting to searching for a specific number like 27. Beautiful Soup doesn't seem to have a function for showing only the text in the top , and recursive=False simply prevents the search from delving below the first level but will still include everything below the first level as contents, so if  at the top level of tags then it will capture it and everything below it

So I think you'd actually have to recurse down the tree of divs and compare the text at each level. I figure this out. It prints in reverse order as it bubbles up from the recursion but that could be stored in a list and output  in forward order.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div>1A<div>2A</div>1B<div>2B<div>3A</div><div>3A</div>2C</div>1C</div>', 'html.parser')

def mangle(node):
    divs = node.find_all('div')
    if len(divs):
        result = [divs[0]] + [n for n in divs[0].next_siblings if n.__class__.__name__ == 'Tag']
        txt = []
        for r in result:
            txt.append(r.__repr__())
            for c in mangle(r):
                txt[-1] = txt[-1].replace(c.__repr__(), '')

        print(''.join(BeautifulSoup(t, 'html.parser').text for t in txt))
        return result
    else:
        return []    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mangle(soup)
```

Basically it walks down the branches of divs and builds lists at each fork of the tree, including the tags, then the caller removes anything found below it leaving just the text that is defined at that level. I keep the tags in place so that text patterns appearing at multiple levels don't get removed by mistake.

Output from the html 1A2A1B2B3A3A2C1C was

```
3A3A
2A2B2C
1A1B1C
```

which is the 3rd, 2nd and 1st nesting levels respectively. Hope this helps.